# How to aggregate several columns into a JSON file in HIVE and avoid nulls

Tags: arrays, json, hive

```
user_id reservation_id  nights  price 
--------------------------------------
AAA     10001             1     100
AAA     10002             1     120
BBB     20003             7     350
ccc     10005                   150
DDD     10007             3
CCC     10006             5
```

to

```
user_id    reservation_details
AAA        [{"nights":"1", "price":"100"}, {"nights":"1","price":"120"}]
BBB        [{"nights":"7", "price":"350"}]
CCC        [{"price":"150"}, {"nights":"3"}]
DDD        [{"nights":"5"}]
```

Here my query is

```
select user_id
       ,concat(" 
               {",concat_ws(',',collect_list(concat(string(reservation_id),": 

              {'nights':",string(nights),",'price':",string(price),"}"))),"}")  as 
      reservation_details 
from  mytable
group by user_id
```

I want to eliminate the columns which have value as nulls and convert that single quotes into double quotes which looks like a exact JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Using in-built datatypes `map` and `array` along with a `case` expression to handle `null`s.

```
select user_id,collect_list(map_nights_price)
from (select user_id,
      case when nights is null then map('price',price)
           when price is null then map('nights',nights)
      else map('nights',nights,'price',price) end as map_nights_price
      from mytable
      where not (price is null and nights is null) --ignore row where price and nights are null
     ) t 
group by user_id
```

Comment: Tried and it error ed. UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are accepted but map<string,string> was passed as parameter 1.

Comment: not sure about the underlying data..it works for me with the example data shown.

Comment: all my hive columns dataypes are string only. Also i need in JSON format. If i have 10 more cloumns and need to check each column whether it is null or not? IS there any dyamic way of checking nulls instead of hardcoding. I know in Java we can achive thru UDF. but want to know in HIVE.